# How to add the Author/Edit mode condition in sightly/HTL for class attribute values.?

Tags: aem, sightly, aem-6, htl

I have a HTML snippet as below.

```
 <div id="mydivid" class="abcd xyz myclass">
....
...
</div>
```

I have wrote it in below way. but it doesn't shows the entire dive in wcmmode=disabled.

```
<div data-sly-test.editor="${wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.design}">
<div id="mydivid" class="abcd xyz myclass">
</div>
....
...
<div data-sly-test.editor="${wcmmode.edit || wcmmode.design}">
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to add *"myclass"* value to the class attribute alone only in author mode and not in preview or disabled mode of AEM page.

Answer (score 5):

HTL provides better flexibility to write test conditions which avoids using the JSTL style if conditions. Your code can be easily written as shown below

```
<div id="mydivid" class="abcd xyz ${wcmmode.disabled ? '' : 'myclass'}"></div>
```

In case you don't want any classes in publish, then

```
<div id="mydivid" class="${wcmmode.disabled ? '' : 'abcd xyz myclass'}"></div>
```

The [HTL specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/1.4/SPECIFICATION.md) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<sly data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}">
<div id="mydivid" class="abcd xyz myclass">
</div>
</sly>
<sly data-sly-test="${wcmmode.disabled}">
<div id="mydivid" class="abcd xyz">
</div>
</sly>
```

Try this, as it will display your myclass only in edit mode, in wcmode=disabled mode, it will display the resepctive class without myclass